# ngc looking in wrong directory

Tags: angular, angular2-aot, angular-compiler-cli

I have installed the `@angular/compiler-cli` globally and added the following **tsconfig-aot.json** to my client directory:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "types": []
  },
    "exclude": [
        "../node_modules"
    ],

  "angularCompilerOptions": {
   "genDir": "aot",
   "skipMetadataEmit" : true
 }
}
```

as recommended in the angular docs. I then run `ngc -p tsconfig-aot.json` in my client directory but get the following error:

> Error: Compilation failed. Resource file not found: C:/Users/George/Source/Repos/docs/client/components/home/client/components/home/home.html

because that resource isn't there.. my home.html is at `C:/Users/George/Source/Repos/docs/client/components/home/home.html`, tsc works fine and I ahve been using JIT compilation and have a working app, so what is AOT looking in the wrong place for my files?

Comment: I have the same issue. Any news man?

Answer (score 0):

In the component ts file you should change the 'templateUrl' to a **relative path** and add **'moduleId: module.id**'.

Example, from:

```
@Component ({
    selector: "login",
    templateUrl:'app/components/login/login.component.html'
})
```

to:

```
@Component ({
    selector: "login",
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl:'login.component.html'
})
```

That solved my issue, hope it helps...